# Convert a column of unix timestamps to dates

Tags: python, pandas, database, time

I have a dataframe that looks like this. How would I convert each timestamp to a date? This is only showing the head of the dataframe by the way.

```
       timestamp    price
0   1615464598245   297.491325
1   1615469525042   300.784423
2   1615471754237   300.918268
3   1615475174397   302.313760
4   1615478420805   304.688945
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

Use `to_datetime()` method:

```
df['timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'],unit='ms')
```

Output:

```
print(df)

      timestamp                 price
0   2021-03-11 12:09:58.245     297.491325
1   2021-03-11 13:32:05.042     300.784423
2   2021-03-11 14:09:14.237     300.918268
3   2021-03-11 15:06:14.397     202.313760
4   2021-03-11 16:00:20.805     304.688945
```

Comment: Thanks, I originally had this by was missing the unit parameter so the dates were coming out in 1970.

Comment: @marktilbrook If you wish, please consider accepting (and upvoting too!) the answer to signal others that the issue is resolve.d (and also to keep people here motivated in helping others..)